# Throwing method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because it returns a value of type 'Bool'

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling, throw

I get following error:

```
Throwing method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because it returns a value of type 'Bool'; return 'Void' or a type that bridges to an Objective-C class
```

When defining Swift protocol which also needs to be bridged to Objective-C:

```
@objc public protocol Saving {

    func save() throws -> Bool
}
```

Is there an other way to define Swift method which can return `Bool`, potentially throw an error and be `Objetive-C` compatible?

Comment: Why would you want to return a Bool *and* throw? Success/Failure is indicated either by returning true/false or by throwing. – `func save() throws` would be translated to Objective-C as `- (BOOL)saveAndReturnError:(NSError **)error;`

Comment: "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" document is not clear if Swift function throwing error will be converted to the Objective-C method returning BOOL.

Comment: I actually tested it now and looked at the head files generated by Swift and you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the following in Swift:

`func save() throws`

will be translated into:

`(BOOL)saveAndReturnError:(NSError **)error`

in Objective-C. Which explains the limitation.

I know that in the `save()` example, it might not make much sense to return a `Bool` as well as throwing, but I disagree with the comment about it not making sense at all. There might be other use cases where it makes sense. Fx. the inverse example; loading `Bool`'s by using an identifer. Loading a `Bool` might return `true`/`false` or `throw` if loading fails, fx. if the identifier was not found when trying to load.

However unfortunately we cannot do this because of how Swift and Objective-C is being bridged.